# JS increment an array down by 1

Tags: javascript

```
let span = document.querySelector('.myspan')
let arr = [1, 2, 3]

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var x = arr.length
  if (event.keyCode === 40) { // down
    span.innerHTML = arr[x-1]
    x--
  }
})

<span class="myspan"></span>
```

When you press `down` in keyboard, the span should show the last item of the `arr` array. The problem here is when you press again, the x value is always the same `3` so how can I succeffuly decreas it by one so I can see the item before last on second `down` press and so on?

Comment: `var x` is never going to print anything other than the last item in the array. If you want to persist its value declare it outside of the event listener.

Comment: You are initializing x inside the listener. That's your issue. Also use let and const instead of var. Just good programming

Comment: Keep a variable outside of the listener and decrement it at every keypress.

Comment: the problem is my array has a bunch of data that is added dynamically by other events... so I added it inside to make sure the array has all data

Comment: Did you want the array values to stop at the first element when user keeps pressing?

Comment: @Ivan86 not sure what that means. I just want to put the var x inside the event listener.

Comment: Did you want the output to stop at 1 or to circle 3,2,1,3,2,1, ... as user keep pressing key?

Comment: I can make it stop, I just want it to increment for now, not to show 3 always.

Comment: I think my example does exactly what you want. If you haven't solved your problem yet, try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either:

1. Have a variable you remember your position in, or
2. Modify the array

For #1, you'd start out with (for instance);

```
let pos = arr.length;
```

alongside `arr`. Then in your event handler:

```
if (pos > 0) {
    span.innerHTML = arr[--pos]; // `--pos` modifies `pos`, then uses the result
}
```

For #2, if you want to modify the array, you can use the `pop` method to both get the last entry and remove it. So:

```
if (arr.length) {
    span.innerHTML = arr.pop();
}
```

Comment: this works in general assuming my array is outside the event listener, but the problem is my array has a bunch of data that is added dynamically by other events... so I added it inside to make sure the array has all data. won't work outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global variable `indexLocation` that will keep adjusting as you press the down button. I added an extra function `adjustIndexLocation()` that does the necessary computation.

```js
let span = document.querySelector('.myspan')
let arr = [1, 2, 3]
var indexLocation = -1;

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  var arrayLength = arr.length;
  
  if (event.keyCode === 40) {
    adjustIndexLocation(arrayLength);
    span.innerHTML = arr[ indexLocation ];
  }
})


function adjustIndexLocation(arrayLength) {
  indexLocation--;
  if(indexLocation < 0)
    indexLocation = arrayLength - 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="myspan"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

.pop removes the last element from array and returns it

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 40) { // down

    alert(arr.pop())
  } 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You're decrementing the value of `x` not the value of `arr.length`.

`x` is not a *reference* to `arr.length`.

Reading the last value from an array and then lowering the value as two seperate operations is a very long-winded approach to the problem though. Just use [the `pop` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).

```
span.innerHTML = arr.pop();
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote here. We didn't (at the time of answering) know whether the user wanted to keep the array unchanged (actually, I don't think I know that even now). :-) Someone seems to have though that rather firmly, though.